# What is the price pressure?

Tags: finance, market-microstructure, asset-pricing, asset-returns

What is the definition of price pressure and what does it imply?

In a number of paper I read that the price pressure can influence the portfolio returns; can you explain why and in which way it can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to learn more about *price pressure*, you should look after **market impact of metaorders**, which is a more adequate term.

Because of the *microstructure* (i.e. the mix of orderbboks dynamics, trading rules, participants behaviours and habits, etc), the more you buy or sell, the more you influence the price an unfavorable way (for your trades).

- Just think about the orderbooks: you at least consume liquidity in them, pushing the price to an higher level (for a large buy order). This is **instantaneous impact** of an isolated (large) trade.
- then liquidity providers come back in the book, slowly relaxing the price to its former level, except if new information changed the "latent price" (think about a fed annoucement: new information, new price).
- but if you come back with another trade, and another, etc. You prevent the price coming back, creating **transient impact**.
- of course doing this, it can be consider that you provides (or exploit) information, thus the "latent price" slowly and simultaneously glides during the trading of your large *metaorder*.
- At the end of this process you stop trading and can measure your **temporary impact**.
- last but not least the price relaxes at a largest time scale, leading to a situation where only the **permanent impact** of your trade remains in the market.

In [Market Microstructure in Practice](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8967), we provide a picture of empirical market impact measured on more than 300000 metaorders (during at least 4 hours each):

[image]

The y-axis is the price move (expressed in a generic unit).
Before 100%, note the concavity of the impact on price, 
after 100% of the metaorder, you can see the relaxation.

More recently a new paper provided more insight of price impact, splitting price moves between impact and investor's predictions (i.e. alpha): [Market impacts and the life cycle of investors orders, by Emmanuel Bacry, Adrian Iuga, Matthieu Lasnier, Charles-Albert Lehalle](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0217).

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

According to the literature in market microstructure, the price pressure is defined as "the change in price when large quantities of 
a security are traded". [Here](http://newyorkfed.org/research/conference/2010/cb/Ambrose_Cai_Helwege1.pdf)
you can find an example of how price pressure influences the bond market and in which the authors provide a complete definition of the phaenomenon and the relative problem of the information effects.

Other suggestions and help will be grateful.